# I want to know the usage of filepath

Tags: c#

I have made a project in which i have a business logic and a GUI. Now i have to separate them in the same project. where business logic is in different class. In my project there is a file that needs to be loaded from memory. Then manipulations in that file is done in the business logic class and results displayed in the winform. Now i want to give the file path in the business logic class so that any xml file i browse gets displayed on the winform. What is the syntax to do that i.e. to give the file path. Something like 
String filename= (what after this). so that the file gets opened in the winform.

Comment: Please do not re-post your question. This is not helping anyone. If you really want help please respect the basic principles of this forum and also rephrase your question.

Comment: Doesn't look like spam to me.  So he screwed up and asked the same question twice.  The other one is already closed for duplicate.  You going to do the same with this one?  Also, whoever marked this as offensive should get a friggen ban.  Its an abuse of the offensive marker.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you get a file path from the UI and are wondering how to best pass this path to your business logic classes.

A string is a very common and acceptable way to pass a file path from one class to another.

FxCop may complain and request you use a Uri.  I think that's a bit of overkill, and the Uri class can be confusing.  I'd suggest skipping it.

Another way is to pass a FileInfo.  Your UI gets the file path from the user, creates a FileInfo, and determines from this if the file exists and if its available to the user.  If it isn't, the UI reports back to the user and waits for input.  If it is, just pass the FileInfo to your business logic.  There it can be used to construct a stream that an XmlReader can consume.

Of the three I'd say 3 sounds the best.  The first is done more often, however.

Comment: Thanks will...But how do we pass a file path from one class to another. Please tell me the syntax.

Comment: Just pass it as a string.  var fileName = @"c:\temp.txt"; var c2 = new   SomeOtherClass();  c2.HeresTheFile(fileName);